# Travelling to Europe. Query regarding Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, france, switzerland

My wife is currently studying in UK and I am from India. I ll be applying from India and She will be applying for Visa from UK to visit France and Switzerland. There are certain concerns I face for the same.

1. How to show the financial means same for both the applications?
2. If I were to courier her my bank statements how old should be the statements?
3. She also has bank account in UK which is just one month old when applying, should she use that account?
4. Our Marriage Certificate is with her, how do I explain this dilemma to the Embassy?
5. I just have tax returns of last two years. Is that okay?
6. Also I ll be entry and leaving via France. I ll stay almost same time in both France and Switzerland. Which Consulate should I apply to?

PS: I just want to be very careful. I ll be meeting my wife after three months.

Answer (score 1):

> How to show the financial means same for both the applications?

Do you need to show that the financial means are the same? If they are the same, great. If not, you can provide separate documents for both. Or say that one is supporting the other.

> If I were to courier her my bank statements how old should be the statements?

Anything reasonable should be okay. For example, a month before the date you apply.

> She also has bank account in UK which is just one month old while Time of applying , should she use that account?

If she had just entered the UK as a student and wasn't there before, then by all means. Even if she hasn't been there for that long, but it provides financial sufficiency, then yes.

> Our Marriage Certificate is with her, how do I explain this dilemma to the Embassy?

Tell the embassy that she is a student studying abroad while you are being interviewed or in a cover letter. Get a copy of the marriage certificate to submit with the rest of your documents.

> I just have tax returns of last two years.Is that okay?

Yes, that is perfectly fine.

IN GENERAL: Embassies just want to know that you are going to the place you say you are going to with the proper purpose. So, what you need to go in general, is provide documents that show that you are indeed going there to be a tourist, and that you have no intention to stay for a longer period of time. What may support this is having a job in your home country, or being enrolled for classes, or land, or other investments. This shows the genuineness of your intent to come back and really just go to France/Switzerland to go on a vacation!

I've applied for a lot of Schengen visas, and it gets scary at times, but it will all turn out okay! Hope this helps!

Comment: Should I also attach my wifes identity  in my application  and so also mine in her application?

Comment: By identity do you mean ID card? If so, yes, if it helps prove the other documents involved.